# How to make an ascendant sort of the data for the column B and keep the associated values for the debit and credit?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, account

**Good morning to the community.**

I'm working on Google Sheets. I'm using Apps Script. You can find my file in the following link.

- [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ce5sppfkftIh0uDsODDmXb_9Cd-hfh5w_q3lIoIS5o8/edit?usp=sharing]

I have one sheet named "journal" where I have the data of my journal.

| Journal |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Année | 2022 |  |  |  |
| Mois | 3 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Date | Compte | Détail des opérations | Débit | Crédit |
| 06-mars | 6 | Groover | 24,00 |  |
| 06-mars | 512 | Banque |  | 24,00 |
|  |  | facture fournisseur n° |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 12-mars | 7 | Bus balladium concert |  | 135,00 |
| 12-mars | 53 | Caisse | 135,00 |  |
|  |  | versement client n° |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 28-mars | 6 | Groover | 24,00 |  |
| 28-mars | 512 | Banque |  | 24,00 |
|  |  | facture fournisseur n° |  |  |
|  |  | Totaux à reporter | 183,00 | 183,00 |

I have also one sheet named "grand livre" where I tried to report the data of the sheet "journal" and sort the data of the accounts (column B) in an ascendant way.
But, the line 9 with the account "7" is not at the end and should be at the end.

|  |  |  | Débit | Crédit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06-mars | 512 |  |  | 24 |
| 28-mars | 512 |  |  | 24 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 12-mars | 53 |  | 135 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 12-mars | 7 |  |  | 135 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 06-mars | 6 |  | 24 |  |
| 28-mars | 6 |  | 24 |  |
|  |  | à reporter | 183 | 183 |

```
function monGrandLivre() {
  var journal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('journal')
  var data = journal.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(r => (!isNaN(Date.parse(r[0]))))
  data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
  });
  var result = []
  result.push(['', '', '', 'Débit', 'Crédit'])
  data.forEach(function (donnees, ligne) {
    result.push([donnees[0], donnees[1], '', donnees[3], donnees[4]])
    if (ligne != (data.length - 1)) {
      if (data[ligne + 1][1] != data[ligne][1]) {
        result.push(['', '', '', '', ''])
        result.push(['', '', '', '', ''])
      }
    }
  })
  var grandLivre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('grand livre')
  grandLivre.clearContents()
  grandLivre.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
  grandLivre.getRange(result.length + 1, 3).setValue('à reporter')
  grandLivre.getRange(result.length + 1, 4).setFormula('=sum(D2:D' + result.length + ')')
  grandLivre.getRange(result.length + 1, 5).setFormula('=sum(E2:E' + result.length + ')')
}
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your sheet images are a bit small and hard to read and if you could post it as a table then we could copy and paste and use it to assist you with your code

Comment: Ok Cooper, I learn some tutos to do tables and I edit the post.

Comment: I don't think it's seeing you dates as Date() objects because they are incomplete.  If they are real date object you can get them with getValues() or just change there formatting.

Comment: If you wish to sort by Dates then I think this `data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
  });` should be `data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[0] - a[0];
  });` but currently it is just sorting alphabetically because it's not seeing column one as real Date() objects

Comment: Ok, I try to put the format of my column with the dates as Date() objects and I try your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort column B by text and not by value, change as follows

```
  data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ('' + a[1]).localeCompare(b[1]);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MikeSteelson ! You solved my problem.